# Sumif across multiple sheets, specific rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have 20 sheets (let's say three, for simplicity) and I need to sumif each of those sheets against one main tab with all the data in it. Each sheet is for a different business entity but each sheet has the same format:

[Format: Business 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XDPk.png)
[image: Format: Business 1000]

[Format: Business 2000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWrIP.png)
[image: Format: Business 2000]

I will insert monthly data into the DATA tab and will need a macro to go into Sheet 1, 2, 3 etc. and run a sumif against the DATA tab matching column B (business unit code). I will also have this run for each month so Row3 will have Actual or Forecast.

The problem:

- DATA tab gets deleted and reset with next month's data, therefore all sumifs must change into values.
- not all rows are equal, some may have 5-6 items and then a Sum for the total, eg: travel may include hotel, parking, meals, car rental. So SumIF can only run where column B has a code. Otherwise do NOTHING.
- I don't know how to code a relative reference inside sumif. I can VBA code a column and tell it to enter "Text" into each non-blank cell. Although I can't tell it to change or have relative cell data.

Then for next month (when data tab gets reset) the next column must be filled in. If it's simpler I can add another row with an X in the active month's column, so the macro can check if there is an X in that row, then do the sum if for that column.

It's simple to run a sum if, copy paste to all non blank rows, and then recopy as value only. But not when I have 20+ sheets, and need to do that every month.

Comment: `searched the forums, read through "Vba for Dummies" and tried a lot of online resources` If all of that is true and you still can't figure it out, may I suggest you hire someone?

Comment: i didn't think this request was so big i needed to go ahead and hire someone. I understand if you don't want to help me. I want to learn it myself and ask the forums help on how to get this going.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's not that bad for a first question @findwindow, i'm sure we could be a little more helpful. First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow - as findwindow mentioned you should probably read the rules and try to include some examples (code) of your attempts so far.

Comment: You sound like you know how to use a sumif, so I will give you some code in an answer that will loop all sheets and use `worksheetfunction.sumif` to set the value directly but I will leave the rest up to you so you can learn.

Comment: @NickDewitt it's funny. Just having a discussion about it. I am torn between upholding SO standards and being kind XD

Comment: @findwindow haha yeah I know mate, me too - I have seen a lot worse than this hitting the review queue though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is an example of what you want to do. In this example, I have left it up to you to set in the code which column you are looking to fill this month.

Change the value of `Const ColumnNumber = 4` to change the column you are filling this month `4=D, 5=E etc` (Apologies I only work in R1C1 ref style).

`FirstRow` always appears to be 4, but I have left that there in case you need to change it.

Worksheetfunction.sumif takes parameters in the same order as the normal sumif, so I am passing in column 1 of the data sheet for the range, cell c of the same row as the criteria, and column 2 of the data sheet as the sum range.

Using `worksheetfunction.sumif` will return the value to the cell, not the formula so that solves your problem of the data sheet being deleted and recreated.

I have also left the option for you to fill in the green rows with something else.

```
    Const ColumnNumber = 4
    Const FirstRow = 4

    Sub LoopSomeSheets()

        Dim sht As Worksheet

        'go through each sheet in the workbook
        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            'ignore the sheet named "data"
            If sht.Name <> "data" Then

                Dim LastRow As Long
                'figure out where the sheet ends
                LastRow = sht.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

                'variable to sum totals
                Dim RunningTotal as Double 

                For i = FirstRow To LastRow

                    If sht.Cells(i, 3).value = "SUM" Then
                        'Put the total value in the sum cell
                        sht.Cells(i, ColumnNumber).value = RunningTotal
                        'reset the total for the next group
                        RunningTotal = 0
                    Else

                        Dim SumOfData as Double
                        'get the sumif value
                        SumOfData = _
                         WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheets("data").Columns(1), sht.Cells(i, 2), Sheets("data").Columns(2))
                        'add to the running total
                        RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SumOfData 
                        'then update the cell
                        sht.Cells(i, ColumnNumber).value = SumOfData 
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next sht
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Nick, i'll have a go at it.

edit: thank you for the green notes. definitely helps me to understand what is going on.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to pop back and ask questions here in the comments if you struggle :)

Comment: hi nick, you said "so I am passing in column 1 of the data sheet for the range, cell c of the same row as the criteria, and column 2 of the data sheet as the sum range."
but it seems it is taking column (1) as the sum range?


 `WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheets("data").Columns(1), sht.Cells(i, 2), Sheets("data").Columns(1))`

Comment: oh yeah, i put in column 1 twice - but yeah you have it, it's the same function but called through code once rather then every time you calculate the sheet in the cell

Comment: I updated it to the second column and ran it with data in the DATA tab in column 1 and 2.. and nothing is happening? 
I also would like my green rows to not be affected by the macro so I left it as is.

Comment: are you matching on codename or fullcode, e.g. what's in column 1 of the data sheet?

Comment: Data tab:
column 1 = Full code (eg: 1000-5555)
column 2 = $100.00

Comment: updated again, sorry ur column is empty my bad changed the line below `'figure out where the sheet ends` `LastRow = sht.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`

Comment: youre an absolute genius.


testing now against my main file and not my test file. will get back to you.
i am so happy. thank you.

Comment: No prob, hope that helps you get started - if you want to learn more I would suggest trying to automate the population of your sum row too. Feel free to come back and ask if you get stuck - and if you could mark this as the answer that would be most appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi Nick, the sum row is already filled in.. so that's not necessary, the format of the sheet never changes.

Although, instead of the green row having the word sum, can I tell the Macro to if it is blank? how do i transpose the ISBLANK function into vba?

if(isblank(sht.cells(i,3).value) then ...?

Comment: ISEMPTY(sht.cells(i,3).value) then


wow i did it.
no.
you did it.


thank you!

Comment: See, there you go you are learning and doing it yourself - we might have us a new vba ally yet @foundwindow lol

Comment: Nick,
how can I automate that sum? when there are different rows per sum how do i tell it to sum 2 rows above, and then 3, then 10, then 2. Can i tell it to sum all values above until it hits a =sum already?

Comment: check my updated answer, I have added a running total, and passed the sum to a variable so I can add it to the running total before setting the value in the cell. Then, when I hit the SUM row I reset the running total after setting that value into the cell.

Comment: it's adding a 0 underneath each of my FULLCODEs where it is blank, cell B6 and B9 in my images and not updating the January column. analyzing it now..

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't be 0 - but the cell it sets should be `sht.Cells(i, ColumnNumber)` not `sht.Cells(i, 3)` - updated again

Comment: Nick, i don't think running total is what we're looking for.

in my image in my OP, D6 must be =sum(d4:d5). and d9 must be =sum (d7:d8), and d15 must be =sum(d10:d14)

Comment: yes i changed it to (i,columnnumber) and it errored again then i posted, sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: yeah, rather than using the sum functions, we are adding the values we get from the sumif in the `worksheetfunction.sumif`, putting them in the sum row and resetting that count to 0 for the next lot. Make sure you copy my code again and change the `ISEMPTY` bit to make sure you get the whole change. When you say it's erroring, what line is the error on and what does it say?

Comment: i changed something and it works now. your code works. yes i changed the isempty, adjusted for new columns and rows. and it's magnificent

Comment: If you are thinking now in terms of `A1` `A2` etc, when converting to programming ur addressing a 2d array - try changing ur reference style to R1C! (options - formulas - tick R1C1 reference style) then you get a numerical reference for columns :)

Comment: Nick. before i send you 1 million internet hugs and love.. What if i have more than one sheet that i want this macro to ignore. how do i change line:
if sht.name <> "data" then
for multiple sheet names to ignore multiple sheets?

Comment: simplest way is to go with `and` so `if sht.name <> "data" and sht.name <> "moredata" then`, or if all the sheets that you want to update are like '1000', '2000' etc you could check if the sheet name is a number before updating - e.g. `if IsNumeric(sht.name) then`

Comment: Nick, that makes sense. Thank you. I realized that the SUM rows (green rows) contain the actual value and not the formula itself. Not that it matters I just wanted to point that out.
wow this honestly has been amazing. is there anything i can do to support you or do something for you in return? Thank you so much for your help you've saved me plenty of time and headaches. I can't thank you enough

Comment: No prob, you are welcome mate I am happy just to be giving back to a site that has helped me to learn so much (I am completely self taught - or stack taught lol) - if you are good with data vba is a great way into programming, and vb.net is a very mature language these days when you feel you want to advance.